# Function from C++/CLI to C#

Tags: c#, c++-cli

I want to convert this code from C++ to C#:

```
array<String^,2>^ SelectARows(String^ myConnectionString, String^ inlist) 
{
PrintToErrorFile("Entering SelectARows...");

array<String^,2>^ names = gcnew array<String^,2>(1200,4);
try{
    OleDbConnection^ myConnection = gcnew OleDbConnection(myConnectionString);
    size_t found;
    found=myConnectionString->IndexOf("PIOLEDB");
    int pifound = 0;
    if (found!=string::npos){
    pifound = int(found);
    }
    String^ mySelectQuery;

    if(pifound > 0){
        mySelectQuery = "select tag, time, value, status FROM piarchive..pisnapshot WHERE tag in (" + inlist +")";
}
```

`PrintToErrorFile` is another function I've created, I'm not familiar with this Visual C++ a lot, any help will be great :)

Comment: You'll need to have a go at this yourself and then post specific questions if you are stuck. "Do this for me"-type questions will generally be frowned upon and closed by the community.

Comment: i'm not familiar with c++/cli a lot, for example this code: `array<String^,2>^ names = gcnew array<String^,2>(1200,4); `is science fiction for me !

Comment: This code does not make any sense. lots of brackets are not closed and the variable "names" is never used. Also, pifound is an int but it should rather be a bool (instead, the bool is casted to an int). I think the first task (before translating it to c#) will be to understand what the code is supposed to do.

Comment: @Christian, i didn't want to put the whole code here coz it doesn't make any sense, i wanted just a push to start and then, i would finish it myself, but if u want to see the full code here it's: [link](http://pastebin.com/vn92aXEU)

Comment: Ah i see. Well as for the line you mentioned in your previous comment: array<String^,2>^ names = gcnew array<String^,2>(1200,4); This will create a two-dimensional array of type String. In c# this could be String[,] names = new String[1200,4];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string[,] SelectARows(string myConnectionString, string inlist) 
{
    PrintToErrorFile("Entering SelectARows...");

    string[,] names = new string[1200,4];

    // I don't know what your intent is for myConnection, as you didn't finish your
    // try block, but it will be autodisposed by the using block.  Maybe this isn't your
    // intent, but no matter what myConnect should be disposed since it implements
    // IDisposable
    using(OleDbConnection myConnection = new OleDbConnection(myConnectionString)) {
        // technically, this should be >= 0, but I'm going from  your code
        bool found = myConnectionString.IndexOf("PIOLEDB") > 0;

        string mySelectQuery = null;

        if(found)
            mySelectQuery = "select tag, time, value, status FROM piarchive..pisnapshot WHERE tag in (" + inlist +")";
        // at this point mySelectQuery is either null or the query string.

        // honestly, I would prefer this form, which is equivalent
        string mySelectQuery = found ? "select tag, time, value, status FROM piarchive..pisnapshot WHERE tag in (" + inlist +")"
                                     : null;
    }
}
```

You might try compiling the code in C++/CLI and then look at it with [.NET reflector](http://www.reflector.net/) with C# turned on to get you started.

Answer (score 3):

Only the array syntax ought to be a stumbling block.  This is the C# version:

```
string[,] names = new string[1200,4];
```